# Character is teleporting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a NPC in my game and he needs to move when it's his turn. It's a tactical RPG. He has a rigidbody attached to him as well. I'm using this function to move him, this script is attached to him:

```
 public void MoveNPC ()
         {
             if (!randomized && mov.gameManager.NPCTurn)
             {
                 randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 1);
                 randomized = true;

                 if (randomNumber == 0 && MonsterPosition.GridPositionNPC.x > 1)
                 {
                     targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
                     targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x;
                     targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z - movMax;
                     myRigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity *Time.fixedDeltaTime));
                 }


   if (randomNumber == 1 && MonsterPosition.GridPositionNPC.x < 7)
                 {
                     targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
                     targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x;
                     targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z + movMax;
                     myRigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity *Time.fixedDeltaTime));
                 }

                 if (this.transform.position == targetPosition)
                 {
                     IsMoving = false;
                 }
             }
         }
```

I call this function in FixedUpdate():

```
void FixedUpdate()
     {
         Player PlayerPosition = HumanPlayer.GetComponent<Player>();
         NPC MonsterPosition = this.GetComponent<NPC>();

         if (MonsterPosition.GridPositonNPC.x != PlayerPosition.GridPosition.x || MonsterPosition.GridPositonNPC.y != PlayerPosition.GridPosition.y)
         {
             IsMoving = true;

             if (IsMoving)
             {
                 MoveNPC();
             }
         }
     }
```

If I use this line of code the NPC moves just a little bit  at a time:

```
 myRigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity *Time.fixedDeltaTime));
```

However, if I don't use `*Time.fixedDeltaTime` he goes where he needs, but he teleports, the velocity value is 10.0f. I get the NPC ridigbody in Start().

What could I be doing wrong here guys? Any thoughts?

Comment: What is wrong with your npc moving just a little bit at a time? what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want him to move until he reaches the target position. He goes there when I remove ```*Time.fixedDeltaTime```, however he teleports.

Comment: What exactly happens when you include `fixedDeltaTime` and why isn't it the behavior you want?

Comment: @Jake When I include it, the NPC barely moves to the target position and that's why I don't want this behavior. He doesn't move at all.